# Given two adjacency matrices, how can I find if they're isomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Matrix 1:
\begin{matrix}
0&1&1&0\\
1&0&1&0\\
1&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&0
\end{matrix}

Matrix 2:
\begin{matrix}
0&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1\\
1&0&1&0
\end{matrix}

I've looked on google to find out how to do this, but I can't find an answer that makes sense to me. As far as I can tell, there is no efficient algorithm to do this, so you need to check all the permutations... but I don't even know how to start. Any help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Draw the graphs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As isomorphims have to preserve degree, there are only 2 possible ones, the first given by 
$$ \phi_1 \colon 1\mapsto 3, 2 \mapsto 4, 3 \mapsto 1, 4 \mapsto 2 $$
and 
$$ \phi_2 \colon 1\mapsto 4, 2 \mapsto 3, 3 \mapsto 1, 4 \mapsto 2 $$
$\phi_1$ maps the first matrix to (that means the following matrix has $a_{\phi_1^{-1}(i), \phi_1^{-1}(j)}$ as $(i,j)$-th entry.
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
0&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&1\\
1&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and so $\phi_1$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a better way of finding a solution to your question.
As the question is given in **MATRIX** form. I think it's better to do total solution in Matrices.

**Concept** : **Matrix  M** be the matrix we get by multiplying adjacency matrix and its **TRANSPOSE (A')**.

```
  Matrix M will be = [a ij] : where a ij is the number of edges from Vi to Vj if i is not equal to j and a ii is the number of edges incident to i(V is the vertices set of the given matrix).
```

So if we find Matrices M1 and M2 for the two given matrices..and checking whether identical terms are there are not. If identical numbers are there in Matrices, then both graphs are **ISOMORPHIC.**
and from these matrices (if they are ISOMORPHIC)we find which element of first graph points to which element of second graph.